# Appending to a file suffix range with echo and tee

Tags: shell-script, pipe, tee

I am unable to figure out how to properly pipe and tee to append to a range of files. Instead of manually typing them out

```
echo "help!" | tee >> file1 file2 file3
```

I am trying to figure out:

```
echo "help!" | tee >> ~/file*
```

I have tried one line commands and tried making a loop using ls, echo, and touch but I am still unsure how to pipe a list of files into tee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-a` flag to `tee` to tell it to append, so if you really have files that match `~/file*` you can do

```
echo "help!" | tee -a ~/file*
```

or whatever list of files you actually want

If you don't already have those files as @steeldriver surmises, you could create, say, 5 files like

```
echo "help!" | tee -a ~/file{1..5}
```

to create `file1` through `file5`

Comment: I think the OP may be looking for something like brace expansion (to create the files if necessary) rather than a simple file glob

Comment: @steeldriver ok, edited to include that case, thanks

Comment: @EricRenouf thank you! I tried the -ia earlier thinking that was the problem I must've been fat fingering something!